# When typing in android firefox browser the keyboard is making my screen smaller

Tags: android, html, css, svg, keyboard

I am writing a html page for cross platform,where i have some text fields. when i try to type inside a text box in an android smartphone, when i type the keyboard is coming out, but it makes my html page smaller inside to come up from the page.

Can someone tell me why its doing this?

Here is the **css** code:

```
    body { background:#ffffff; margin:0 } 

    html,body{ 
    overflow:hidden;
    }

   .mainbody {
      display:block; border:0px solid #cccccc; position:absolute;
      top:0vmin; left:0vmin; width:100%; height:100%; background:#ffffff;
    }

    .homeScreen1 {
     position:absolute;  
      display:block; border:0px solid #cccccc;
      background:#CDCDCD;
    }

.e-number{
     position:absolute; 
    left:11vmin;
    top:8vmin;
    font-size: 2.7vmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with;

```
.mainbody {
width:100%;
Height:100%;
}
```

Not sure if that's the case thought, can't imagine Android would make the sitescreen smaller for the keyboard thought...

I'm also not quite sure why you are putting **overflow: hidden** on your **html, body**.
Could you explain?

Comment: overflow: hidden is to hide the scroll in browsers! bat the mainbody have the width and the height

Comment: Well if it's to prevent scrollbars, couldn't that be the reason it looks like the keyboard is making the sitescreen smaller?.. You're gonna have to need scrollbars at some point.